# Internationalization in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I have problem with Internationalization in SAPUI5.

I have a folder i18n and it has a file i18n.properties and inside it has NAME=app name
SERVER= server name

I have a shell and inside onInit I have this code :

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel({bundleUrl:"./i18n/i18n.properties"});
      sap.ui.getCore().setModel(oModel, "i18n");
```

then I go to my View and and use it in my shell like this:

```
oShell = new sap.ui.ux3.Shell({
      id:"main-shell",
      appTitle:"{i18n>NAME}",
      showPane:false,
      showLogoutButton:false,
      showTools:false,
  });
```

this works fine.But when I go to another view and use it to get the server address it doesn't work for example i go to another controller and use it like this:

```
var URL="{i18n>SERVER}";
```

this code doesn't get resolved and stay the same as it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are trying to bind the value to a varaible, what you need to do is read from the bundle directly, one way to get the value is

```
var URL = sap.ui.getCore().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle().getText("SERVER");
```